# Refreshing VisualForce page using PageReference removes errors on the page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to refresh a visual force page with the following code:

```js
PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();   //Create page reference to the same page          
tempPage.setRedirect(true);     //Set the redirect property to true
return tempPage;    //Return the page reference to refresh the page
```

The problem is that if refresh is done in such a way, it does not show errors on the page.
Is there a way to show error on the page after refreshing the page? I did not find any help online.

Note: I am not using `return null;` to refresh the page because it maintains the state of the variables and I get an error `confirm form resubmission` each time I refresh using browser. Please guide. Thank You!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't wipe out the state and preserve the errors (you do see the conflict in that, don't you?). Instead, you'd want to check if there are errors, and if so, don't clear the state, since the user will need to do whatever they just did again while correcting the errors. Try:

```
tempPage.setRedirect(!ApexPages.hasMessages());
```